# A REST api backed JavaScript table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, rest

Here's the problem:

I need a table I can quickly 'plug' into my webapp.

I have existing REST endpoints for getting the table data in JSON, either with pagination or without. Now, if I could only find a JS table component that I would configure to use my endpoints (I can modify them to meet the tables requirements).

Misc: If the table requires jQuery that's fine with me, and utilizing Twitter Bootstrap CSS is optional and much welcomed.

Comment: I use jqGrid, it has an API for JSON data http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html  (under "Loading data" section)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Toni said in his comment, [jqGrid](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) is probably your best bet for quick results, and it has extensive styling options. Be aware though that the HTML it produces is quite verbose. If you are deploying to mobile it may make sense just to spit out your own HTML table. This is dead simple if you are using jQuery already.

Comment: I'll go with jqGrid and do my own implementation later when I'll have more time as it turns out..